# C String Pointers

Tags: c

why is it not possible for sscanf() to write the string into char* s? I initialised it to NULL as I do not want uninitialised variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char* t = "I am a monkey";
    char *s = NULL;
    sscanf(t, "%s",s);
    printf("%s\n",s);


}
```

Comment: Think of what it means to initialize a pointer to `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow your train of thought. I am not able to understand why sscanf cannot simply change NULL to an address of a string.

Comment: There is a need to secure an area to be written. `char *s = malloc(16);` instead of `char *s = NULL;`. (malloc  #include <stdlib.h> then `printf("%s\n",s);free(s);`）

Comment: @kuan It can't because it is specified to do something else. Read the docs.

Comment: `sscanf(t, "%ms", &s);` when use glibc. (`free(s)`);

Comment: @kuan re: your comment.  C functions are **pass by value**, so sscanf is passed a copy of `s` (which contains `NULL`).  It cannot change the value of `s`.  Look up pass by value if you are still confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line `char *s = NULL` creates a variable that holds the memory address of a character.  Then it sets that memory address to zero (`NULL` is address zero).

Then the line `sscanf(t, "%s",s);` tries to write the contents of `t` to the string at the location `s`.  This will segfault because your process cannot access address zero.

Your instincts were good to avoid uninitialized variables, but you traded this for unallocated pointers!

Fix this by allocating some space on the stack (or heap) for s by declaring:

```
char s[STRING_LENGTH];
```

Where `STRING_LENGTH` is `#defined` to be however many characters you want to allocate.  This allocates a chunk of memory to hold the null-terminated character array and sets `s` to the address of the first character

Answer (score 1):

Here sscanf defination says that,,,

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);

sscanf(t, "%s",s);
```

So here it will take text from source as `t` but on destination side s is just pointer to `Null`  there is no memory.

So allocate some memory to s using `malloc` or  assign `s` to some valid memory location.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it not possible for sscanf() to write the string into char* s? I initialised it to NULL

*The string functions in the C standard library do not allocate storage.* All they do is copy things around. You have to manage every byte of string storage yourself. This will seem strange to someone coming from pretty much every other language.

In other words, you have to point *s to some memory for sscanf to write into. If you use NULL then sscanf writes to memory that starts at address NULL (usually 0).